# Switch to last active session in tmux

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

I want to know is it possible to switch to last session I visited in tmux.

For e.g., suppose I was in pane 1 of `session A` and I switched to pane 1 in `session B` (using `PREFIX s` and selecting the pane 1 in `B`). Now I want to switch back to pane 1 of `session A`.

Is there any keybinding for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switch between sessions:

```
C-b (          previous session
C-b )          next session
C-b L          ‘last’ (previously used) session
C-b s          choose a session from a list
C-b w          choose a session or a windows within a session from a list
```

Comment: A light... in the black... or just a fear... of the doge...